# Vsual Studio Code Restarting the terminal because the connection to the shell process was lost

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Visual studio code console gives the following error after running for a long time without shutting down (1-2 days).

```
Restarting the terminal because the connection to the shell process was lost...
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7964, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69999785/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/73060854/11107541

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Windows
'Developer: Reload Window'

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: me too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that the latest VSCode and Python extensions are installed.

Use the following setting to increase the maximum number of buffers

```
    "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 10000,
```

In addition, you can try to use external terminal.

```
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
```